# run program in background

Tags: linux, xz

Is it possible to run a program e.g. `xz` in the background so it wouldn't suck all the system's resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [change the priority](http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/changing-priority-on-linux-processes/) for running processes. The lower the nice value, the more resources are allocated to that task above others. Setting a higher positive value (I believe this is measured from -20 to +19) would allocate almost no resources to the task, and it will be processed only when there is nothing else to be done.

Answer (score 1):

How To Limit Resources Using cgroups on CentOS 6
If you don't want your program to suck all the system resources then you can use cgroups [(example of how to use cgroups in Centos 6)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-limit-resources-using-cgroups-on-centos-6) to limit the resources. You may also want to set higher nice value so that your cpu only process it when less task are present to execute.

Comment: Welcome to superuser: This only provides an answer for Centos, while this is a good addon for the question and searchers other  than a sole answer for an accepted question. Poss comment. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Although the link says its for Centos6 but its not different for any other distribution.